# Are there any prerequisites (besides ability scores) for becoming certain classes from multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

Certain classes, theoretically, and in terms of story, should only be obtained by certain means besides leveling up. For example, sorcerers are theoretically born with their powers, and warlocks should have to gain them from divine beings. Paladins, too, in Keith Baker's (creator of the Eberron campaign setting) personal campaign, which he mentioned in his blog, *have* to be called in order to become a paladin. I was wondering if there are any official rules for these situations, or if it should just be left to the DM's discretion.

Comment: I'm afraid this question will be closed as "opinion-based" since the restrictions you're talking about is completely up to the DM, and DMing styles differ.

Comment: @enkryptor He's asking if official rules exist, or if this is a 'DM discretion' issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## RAW, No.

The prerequisite paragraph on page 163 of the PHB simply says

> To qualify for a new class, you must meet the ability score prerequisites for both your current class and your new one, as shown in the Multiclasssing Prerequisites table.

That's it. That's the only requirement.

Now, on the other hand, from the same page...

> This chapter defines two optional sets of rules for customizing your characters: multiclassing and feats. [...] Your DM decides whether these options are available in your campaign

So, according to the Player's Handbook, Multiclassing is an optional rule that the DM can allow. So a DM can forbid multiclassing altogether.

So, no. There are no additional requirements to multiclass besides "DM Says multiclassing is allowed in this game" and "I meet the ability score requirements."

Any further conditions applied are done so at the DM's discretion as Master of Rules.

Comment: The comic Order of the Stick [poked fun at this](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0126.html) with regards to a Level 1 Wizard requiring decades of study, while multiclassing to wizard is instant.

Answer (score 4):

There are no official rules for multiclassing prerequisites beyond what is listed under Chapter 6 of the PBH. Multiclassing is specifically covered on pages 163-166 and is an Optional rule to begin with (you can opt not to offer it, just like the Feats described later in that chapter.)

Anything additional would be a DM decision and homerule.